# A basis for the profinite topology

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, algebraic-topology, profinite-groups

Let $G$ be a group, and let 
$$C =\{H\leq G  :\  [G:H]<\infty \}$$
$$B_R =\{Hx\leq G  :\ H\in C ,x\in G\}$$
$$B_N =\{Hx\leq G  :\ H\in C ,H\ is\ normal\ in\ G,x\in G\}$$
I want to show that $B_R$ and $B_N$ are bases of the same topology on $G$. I proved that both of them are bases for $G$ and one can easily check that $B_R$ contains $B_N$. Hence it suffices to show that $\forall H \in C \ \exists A\subseteq B_N $ s.t. $\cup A =H$ , but I have no idea more. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use that fact that any subgroup of finite index contains a normal subgroup of finite index.

Comment: thnx. I proved it by using the core :)